# CONNECTIVITY_ACTION receiver goes off in the moment I register it

Tags: android

On Android 7, I know that I have to register the `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`receiver programmatically, and not in the manifest

the receiver goes off in the moment I register it. How do I prevent that?

in My application class I do this:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(new NetworkUpdateReceiver(), filter);
    }
```

and then the `onReceive` method is called right away:

```
public class NetworkUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Context context;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;
        Log.e("NetworkUpdateReceiver", "onReceive");
```

After that it works normally - I get a method invocation every time the network is turned on or off

Comment: It's probably a sticky broadcast. Not much you can do about that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the problem with it firing immediately? Whatever your handler is doing should still be processing the event the same whether it is now or later. It isn't as simple as a toggle back and forth... if that's what you're doing with it.

Comment: The problem is that the app does a series of events whenever network becomes available, which is okay later on but not every time the app is loaded into memory. It seemed to me that it would be easier to prevent it from going off every time, rather than implementing workaround logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**BroadcastReceiver.java** has method isInitialStickyBroadcast(), so to ignore Connectivity change when you register receiver you can write such code:

```
public class NetworkUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Context context;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    if (isInitialStickyBroadcast()) {
        Log.i("NetworkUpdateReceiver", "onReceive ignored, sticky");
        return;
    }
    Log.i("NetworkUpdateReceiver", "Actual onReceive");
```